# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service error when using Aws Sdk in UWP

Tags: wpf, amazon-web-services, uwp, amazon-cognito

I'm working with Aws Sdk and I'm trying to implement a login UI using UWP. I followed [this online tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/sign-up-and-confirm-with-user-pools-using-csharp/) (which is for WPF) and I tried to make it works for the Universal Windows Platform as well.

The core part of the source code is the following (please note that is 90% similar to the one posted in the tutorial. The "only difference" is that I used

> InitiateAuthAsync

instead of

> AdminInitiateAuthAsync

```
    <!-- language: lang-cs -->
    private readonly AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient _client;
    private readonly string _clientId = "32fsoifj93fjsiispat";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var amazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig();
        amazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig.ServiceURL = "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/";
        _client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(amazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig);
    }
    private async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            List<HttpHeader> httpHeaders = new List<HttpHeader>();
            HttpHeader httpHeader = new HttpHeader
            {
                HeaderName = "X-Amz-Target",
                HeaderValue = "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth"
            };
            httpHeaders.Add(httpHeader);
            httpHeader = new HttpHeader
            {
                HeaderName = "Content-Type",
                HeaderValue = "application/x-amz-json-1.1"
            };
            httpHeaders.Add(httpHeader);

            var authReq = new InitiateAuthRequest()
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
            };
            authReq.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", userName);
            authReq.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);

            var authResp = await _client.InitiateAuthAsync(authReq);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please consider that it is working properly with WPF framework. I'm able to get the TokenId and RefreshToken.
But if I try to copy and paste the same code in UWP I get the exception:

> 'Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'

And if I try to investigate with Fiddler I get the following error:

> [Fiddler] The connection to '169.254.169.254' failed. 
> Error: NetworkUnreachable (0x2743). 
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 169.254.169.254:80

I really can't understand why it tries to connect to the '169.254.169.254' address. Googling around I found other people experiencing the same issue (for example [here](https://gitter.im/aws/aws-sdk-net?at=5f3f35c4e51e8541339c03f1)). Do you have any idea?